# Multiple Screen Design on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support, android-screen, multiscreen

I want to design some android layout for multiple screen resolution. Forexample I want to set position for button. It must be set positioned at the bottom of layout for every screen size. How can I design it ? Thanks for attention.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/arayuz" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
        android:text="@string/ara"
        android:textColor="#efefef"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: define "it doesn't work"

Comment: It doesn't seem any difference. @Mohamed_AbdAllah : I read this article but I don't want to create more than one layout for one activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use android:layout_alignParentBottom and  android:layout_centerHorizontal for the button,
it will be shown centered bottom of the screen

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="asdad"
        android:textColor="#efefef"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
```